# MongoDB - Get all documents whose array-type field contains at least one of a list of values

Tags: mongodb

If I have a `parent` collection with docs like:
`{"_id": ObjectId(), "child_ids": [ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2]}`
and I have a list of child ID's like [ObjectID_1, ObjectID_5],
**how can I query for all documents in the `parent` collection where one of my child ID's is contained in that parent's `child_ids` array field?**

Comment: You should use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"child_ids":{"$in":[ObjectID_1, ObjectID_5] }})
```

find objects like

```
{"_id": ObjectId(), "child_ids": [ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2,...]}
..
{"_id": ObjectId(), "child_ids": [ObjectID_10, ObjectID_5,...]}
```

and etc

Comment: Interesting, I did not know '$in' would work with on array arguments. Thanks!

Comment: @djaszczurowski's comment on his own answer below explains that this is OR behavior, and everything now makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

you may use `in` operator

query to run in console:
    `db.parent.find( { child_ids: { $in: [ ObjectID_1 ] } } )`

more info here:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: That's a true statement, but the whole difficulty was that my list had multiple values. You did make it a list, but it's a singleton list, which makes your answer less clear, because if I had only one value, I wouldn't need it to be in a list and thus there would not be confusion about whether or not I could use '$in'.

Comment: values withing $in array work as a boolean OR. so... { $in: [ ObjectID_1, ObjectID_2 ] } will work "give me document which have ObjectID_1 OR ObjectID_2. I put there one item just as an example

Comment: Ooh, that's a great explanation. And actually, that behavior highlights exactly why putting the one item made the example a little less clear. It is hard to see the OR behavior if there's only one item.